# Using matplotlib:

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a csv document an image using matplotlib. How do you print numbers using matplotlib?

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import csv
file =input ("Enter file name in csv: ")
print()
data = []
with open(file,"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    nump = 0 
    for row in reader:
            floatrow = []
            for val in row:
                floatrow.append(float(val))
                data.append(floatrow)
fig = plt.figure()

plt.show()
```

I have never use matplotlib thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Ffisegydd thanks but I have tried and i can't find the right commands

Comment: @MattDMo how could i make a set of numbers appear in order in an image using matplotlib

Comment: how is organized your csv file. Do you have x, y values? Do you have x, y, z values?

Comment: @TommasoF No its just lists of numbers, the main goal would be to then add colors to the minimum values.

Comment: There are many [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) on matplotlib.org, as well as [other documentation](http://matplotlib.org/contents.html). Check out the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) for ideas as well.

Comment: @MattDMo Ive spent the past few hours doing that and i can't seem to get a grasp on it.

Answer (score 2):

This is could be a hint if you want to plot only the values as y-values, you can do this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(len(data)),data)
plt.show()
```

Then you can look into the matplotlib [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/contents.html) and [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) for having an idea of all the styles and what matplotlib offers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to produce a figure that contains a list of numbers that you read in from a csv file. If so, the following command might be useful:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
fig.text(.5, .5, str(4.0))
plt.draw()
```

It will add the string '4.0' to the middle of your figure window (at a location 50% of the height of the figure vertically and 50% of the width of the figure horizontally.